# OVH email manager script using docopt

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, email

This is what I coded to realize a command line program to make it easier to manage emails on ovh shared hostings. It's working ok but it seems ugly.

I'm a beginner with Python and `docopt`.  What would you suggest?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
''' OVH Email Manager (ovhEmailMan)
A small script that helps to add and remove one or more email addresses on the OVH shared domains

    Usage:
        ovh_mails.py list [--ugly]
        ovh_mails.py add (<address> [--pswd=<password>][--description=<description>] | --file <filename> [--notify])
        ovh_mails.py remove (<address> | --file <filename>)
        ovh_mails.py (-h | --help)

    Arguments:
        <password>                        Password to access the mailbox (if not provided it's random generated)
        <filename>                        Name of the files to process (csv). Check README to see how to format it

    Options: 
        -h, --help                        Show this help message
        -u, --ugly                        Print without nice tables
        -p, --pswd=<password>             Set the password to the one provided
        -n, --notify                      If set, notification mail is sent using smtp credentials in ovh.conf

    Commands:
        list                              list all the email addresses currently configured
        add                               add one or more (configured in <filename>) email addresses
        remove                            remove one ore more (configured in <filename>) email addresses
    '''



import ovh
from docopt import docopt
from ovhem import EmailManager
from ovhem import fileprocesser as fp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    #Validate args ---- TODO
    eman = EmailManager()

    # 'List' command parsing
    if args['list']:
        if args['--ugly']:
            eman.niceoutput = False

        eman.list_emails()
    # 'Add' command parsing
    elif args['add']:
        if args['<address>']:

            emails = (
                      {
                       'address': args['<address>'],
                       'password': None,
                       'description': None,
                       },
                      )
            if args['--description']:
                emails[0]['description'] = args['<description>']
            if args['--pswd']:
                emails[0]['password'] = args['<password>']
        if args['--file']:
            emails = fp.process_file(args['<filename>'])    

        # Getting back the emails dict
        emails=eman.add_emails(emails)
        if args['--notify']:
            fp.send_notifications(emails)

    # 'remove' command parsing       
    elif args['remove']:
        if args['<address>']:

            emails = (
                      {
                       'address': args['<address>'],
                       },
                      )
        if args['--file']:
            emails = fp.process_file(args['<filename>'])
        eman.remove_emails(emails)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, it looks quite fine, with some smaller and bigger issues.

#### Parsing the `add` command

It's not so great to use the `'<address>'` string twice here:

> ```
>     if args['<address>']:
>
>         emails = (
>                   {
>                    'address': args['<address>'],
>         # ...
> ```

You might mistype one of them. Or you might change something later and forget to update it everywhere. It would be better to put the value of `args['<address>']` into a variable, and use that variable in evaluations and assignments.

This part is also awkward:

> ```
>         emails = ( ... )
>         if args['--description']:
>             emails[0]['description'] = args['<description>']
>         if args['--pswd']:
>             emails[0]['password'] = args['<password>']
> ```

It would be much easier to use `description` and `password` variables to store defaults, then update these variables if `--description` or `--pswd` were given, and finally create the `emails` tuple.

Like this:

```
    address = args['<address>']
    if address:
        password = None
        description = None
        if args['--description']:
            description = args['<description>']
        if args['--pswd']:
            password = args['<password>']
        emails = (
            {
                'address': address,
                'password': password,
                'description': description,
            },
        )
```

#### Parsing the `remove` command

Here, if the second `if` statement is true,
it will overwrite the effect of the first:

> ```
>     if args['<address>']:
>         emails = (
>             {
>                 'address': args['<address>'],
>             },
>         )
>     if args['--file']:
>         emails = fp.process_file(args['<filename>'])
> ```

That suggest that you should use an `elif`, and switch the order of the statements:

```
    if args['--file']:
        emails = fp.process_file(args['<filename>'])
    elif args['<address>']:
        emails = (
            {
                'address': args['<address>'],
            },
        )
```

#### `emails` might be undefined

Both the parsing of `add` and `remove` have a problem:
As their last step they do something with `emails`,
for example `eman.add_emails(emails)` and `eman.remove_emails(emails)`,
but at that point the `emails` variable might be undefined.

This can be fixed by adding validation for these commands.
It looks that either of these must be true, checked in this order:

- `--file` was specified and `<filename>` parameter was given
- `<address>` parameter was given

For example:

```
if args['--file']:
    filename = args['<filename>']
    if filename:
        emails = fp.process_file(filename)
    else:
        raise Exception("Filename parameter missing")
else:
    address = args['<address>']
    if address:
        emails = ( ... )
    else:
        raise Exception("Address parameter missing")

# main action
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I will refactor as you suggest.